# how to read data from a streaming kafka topic in databricks' notebooks?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I have a kafka topic that I ran on confluent, and now I want to connect to it inside my databricks notebook in order to be able to then use it to build delta live tables (or just delta tables). I seem to be stuck on the phase of "Stream Initializing" and no matter how long I wait, I either get a timeout due to how long it takes, or it just keeps running and never ends.
Therefore I am unsure what I am doing wrong here, I would very much like to receive some help on this matter.

Below is the explanation on the code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

    
kafka_df = (
    spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "<kafkaserver to connect to>")
    .option("subscribe","topic_0")
    .option("kafka.request.timeout.ms", "60000")
    .option("kafka.session.timeout.ms", "30000")
    .load()
)

display(kafka_df)
```

After I run this code, all I get stuck here and never saw any progression from this phase:

[image: infini initialization]

when I put my mouse over the green icon it just tells me its getting offsets.

I have tried the following things:

- adding

```
#     .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
#     .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")
#     .option("kafka.sasl.username", "api_key")
#     .option("kafka.sasl.password","api_secret")
```

This does not seem to make the connection work, what I get after this is that kafka failed to construct a consumer because of the lack of

`.option("sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="USERNAME" password="PASSWORD"";`

After I include this option, well, I am not really sure what is the username and password. Again, all I am trying to do is to be able to read data from this kafka, so I am not sure if an authentication is needed

- using spark.read, instead of spark.readStream. Doesn't change much, I just get an eternal running command.

In any case I really do not know what is wrong with the way i am trying to connect, Any help is appreciated

Comment: Confluent Cloud? Then yes, you have a username and password, as mentioned in Confluent documentation... I.e. your API key/secret